# Linq to sql where [column] in (list of values with other schema)

Tags: linq-to-sql

So here is a join:

```
var multipleSites = (from cs in dc.CUsersSites
                            join c in dc.CUsers on cs.UserId equals c.UserId
                            where cs.Cid == int.Parse(Session["Cid"].ToString()) && c.UserName == HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
                            select cs).ToList();
```

**Schemas**

> ```
> CUsersSites (id, UserId, Cid, Siteid)
> CUsers (id, UserId, UserName)
> Sites (id, Cid, Siteid, FullName)
> ```

How I can get all the `Sites` where `Siteid` is in the `multipleSites` list?

I tried that:

```
this.SitesStore.DataSource = from s in dc.Sites
                                  where s.Cid == int.Parse(Session["Cid"].ToString()) && ( multipleSites.Contains(s.Siteid))
                                  select s;
```

But I get this error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'DAL.CUsersSite'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that approach:

```
this.SitesStore.DataSource = 
dc.Sites.Where(s => multipleSites.Select(ms => ms.Siteid )
.Contains(s.Siteid) && s.Cid == int.Parse(Session["Cid"].ToString())).ToList();
```